# JQuery / $.ajax /alert in .fail, but it succeed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, servlets

I have a little problem when i use ajax in JQuery. 
Let me explain: A user enter login, password, name, email, ... and I use a servlet to create the user's account.

```
$(function(){
$("#subinsc").click(function(){
    var nom=$("#nom").val();
    var prenom=$("#prenom").val();
    var email=$("#email").val();
    var login=$("#login").val();
    var password1=$("#pass1").val();
    var password2=$("#pass2").val();

//verif_form_inscription just check if login and password are ok.
var ok=verif_form_inscription(login,password1,password2);
if(ok){
    $.ajax({
        type:"get",
        async:false,
        url: "HERE IS THE CREATEACCOUNT SERVLET",
        data: {mail : email,login:login,password:password1,nom:nom,prenom:prenom},
        success:function(res){
            alert("ok");
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#popup").show(800);
                $("#insc").replaceWith(jQuery("#popup"));
            }); 
        },
        error:function(res){
            console.log(res);
            alert("fail servlet");
        }

})
};
});})
```

**The servlet always "work", the user is in the dataBase**, **but** on the screen I have the .fail alert and not the succeed alert and the #popup div saying "Welcome, your are registred".

Here is the form balise:

```
<form id="insc" method="get" action="">
```

And the submit balise:

```
<input type="submit" value="SIGN UP" id="subinsc"/>
```

If anyone could help me...
Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: Solved.

Comment: Did you check your network tab to analize the response of the ajax call?

Comment: I tried to analyse doing console.log(res) (apparently, here res is an Object), I have things about Ajax, but i don't know how to analyse.

Comment: The API's are like jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {}), and qXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {}). You can get the status code from jqXHR.status

Comment: What browser are you using for the testing? I know some latest versions of Chrome do not allow async: false.

Comment: I'm using Mozilla. I don't know if it helps, but when I analyse, I have readyState:0, Status:0 StatusText: [Exception... "Failure"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js :: .send :: line 4"  data: no].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing `callback` and `deferred`

Either write in this way

```
$.ajax({
        ..,
        success:function(){
            alert("Ok, succeed");
            ..
        },
        error : function(){
            alert("Fail createuser");
        }
        })
```

OR

```
$.ajax({
        ...
    })
    .done(function() {
        alert("succee");
    }).fail(function() {
        alert("Fail createuser");
    })
```

Comment: Even if i dont mix callback and deferrend, i still have the same problem: it goes in error (or fail) but the servlet "worked".

Comment: It's ok guys, i found the problem (Dunno why, but a WAR export did the job ... ) Thanks for your help.